# Change value in function used by pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am doing the following:

```
def percentage(x):
    return x[(x<=5)].count() / x.count() * 100

full_data = full_data.groupby(['Id', 'Week_id'], as_index=False).agg({'Volume': percentage})
```

But I want to do this `groupby` successively with multiple values such `x<=7`, `x<=9`, `x<=11` etc at the `percentage` function.

What is the easiest way to do this instead of writing multiple functions and calling them?

So basically I want to avoid doing something like this:

```
def percentage_1(x):
    return x[(x<=5)].count() / x.count() * 100

full_data_1 = full_data.groupby(['Id', 'Week_id'], as_index=False).agg({'Volume': percentage_1})

def percentage_2(x):
    return x[(x<=7)].count() / x.count() * 100

full_data_2 = full_data.groupby(['Id', 'Week_id'], as_index=False).agg({'Volume': percentage_2})

# etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your function - create new column filled by boolean mask and then aggregate `mean` and last multiple by `100` with [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html):

```
n = 3

full_data['new'] = full_data['Volume'] <= n
full_data = full_data.groupby(['Id', 'Week_id'])['new'].mean().mul(100).reset_index()
```

Solution with function:

```
def per(df, n):
    df['new'] = df['Volume'] <= n
    return df.groupby(['Id', 'Week_id'])['new'].mean().mul(100).reset_index()
```

EDIT: Solution from [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7186#issuecomment-371255826):

```
full_data = pd.DataFrame({
        'Id':list('XXYYZZXYZX'),
         'Volume':[2,4,8,1,2,5,8,2,6,4],
         'Week_id':list('aaabbbabac')
})

print (full_data)

val = 5
def per(c):
    def f1(x):
        return x[(x<=c)].count() / x.count() * 100
    return f1

full_data2 = full_data.groupby(['Id', 'Week_id']).agg({'Volume': per(val)}).reset_index()
print (full_data2)
  Id Week_id      Volume
0  X       a   66.666667
1  X       c  100.000000
2  Y       a    0.000000
3  Y       b  100.000000
4  Z       a    0.000000
5  Z       b  100.000000
```

---

```
def percentage(x):
    return x[(x<=val)].count() / x.count() * 100

full_data1 = full_data.groupby(['Id', 'Week_id'], as_index=False).agg({'Volume': percentage})

print (full_data1)
  Id Week_id      Volume
0  X       a   66.666667
1  X       c  100.000000
2  Y       a    0.000000
3  Y       b  100.000000
4  Z       a    0.000000
5  Z       b  100.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this as the most concise solution to my question:

```
def percentage(x):
    global c
    return x[(x<=c)].count() / x.count() * 100

c=5
full_data_5 = full_data.groupby(['Id', 'Week_id'], as_index=False).agg({'Volume': percentage})

c=7
full_data_7 = full_data.groupby(['Id', 'Week_id'], as_index=False).agg({'Volume': percentage})

c=9
full_data_9 = full_data.groupby(['Id', 'Week_id'], as_index=False).agg({'Volume': percentage})

# etc
```

However, I am using a global variable and this is a quite controversial practice.